# svn branching and multiple track development

Tags: svn, tags, branch

All,

this is too double check.
I have a product on trunk. I am going to Alpha with it. I will make an alpha branch. The way I see it. To support alpha, the work will be done on the alpha branch and merged to trunk. New work will go on the trunk.

Do I have that correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not specific to SVN but the [Streamed Lines paper](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/acme/branching/) has an excellent discussion of branching patterns

Take a look at the discussion on "[code line (branch) per release](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/acme/branching/branch-creation.html#CodelinePerRelease)"

Answer (score 3):

That works. The [Version Control With Subversion document has a nice chapter on Branching](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) that I found useful to get started.

At my current work we leave the Trunk as the "latest and greatest" and use feature branches. As features are completed they are integrated into the Trunk and then tagged as they move through the release cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. You can do maintenance stuff on the alpha branch (bug fixes maybe), and periodically merge them into trunk if you wish. Meanwhile you can keep on developing new stuff on trunk.